# Throw error from Java to Jsp using sessions/request object

Tags: java, jsp, dao

In my Dao class how shall i pass the error to front end i.e JSP.This is my code

```
public class VehicleDao extends HttpServlet{ 
public void Motor() 

{ 
try { 

}catch (SQLException ex) { 
} 

}
}
```

whenever it enters catch block i want to pass that error to JSP. I tried to create session but i can't do so also i tried using request object in DAO i couldn't could somebody solve this.I am calling this DAO from a controller .Thanks in advance

Comment: set that into request attribute and check in jsp. what's the deal here?

Comment: under catch block i tried this one request.setAttribute("name_excep", ne); where ne is the caught exception. But it didn't worked

Comment: which is your Dao extending HttpServlet.  Where is your `doGet`

Comment: _Dao extends HttpServlet_, this is not a good design at all. If you want to propagate an exception, you should catch it at the right place. Maybe catch exception in Controller or Servlet and there you set the exception in request object and do whatever you want to. Looking at the current code I doubt if your request is being processed at all, no doGet or doPost

Comment: @ScaryWombat this DAO is a simple java class actually no need to extend HttpServlet .I extended it to use sessions

Comment: Just because you extend HttpServlet does not mean that you will access to the Session.  Read @HimanshuBhardwaj comment

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj how to catch exception from DAO and pass it to controller

Comment: Im my opinion the dao should onlt worry about persistence and not worry about what kind of application we are developing. You should\could take your dao package and transfer it from a web application to a standard application without changing anything: dao layer should not worry about it.
That's the way i don't usually try\catch in dao, but I prefer throwing the exception and catching it, for example, in the controller, where i can place the error in the session or where you prefer to pass it to the jsp.

Comment: Don't catch anything in DAO, it will propagate itself to higher layers, or if you are using custom exceptions which I doubt, you can wrap SQLException in the custom one and throw the same using **throw** keyword.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj could you show me some piece of code that i may exploit your concept

Comment: Search in google "exception propagation in java" there are tonnes of samples.